# Как подключить api яндекс карт к folium

Tags: python, api, yandex-maps-api, folium, streamlit

Либо я плохо ищу, либо этой информации действительно нет.
Хочу подключить Я.карты к folium, api ключ у меня есть, и да, я видел как подключали Mapbox, тут же я не знаю, какой tails должен быть.

В mapbox это выглядит так:

```
folium_map = folium.Map(location=[-8.907970, 33.433200],
                    zoom_start=7,
                    tiles='http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/(username).(mapid)/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token=(access token)',
                    attr='Mapbox')
```

Однако, как это должно выглядеть с Яндекс Картами или 2gis api?

Я представляю себе картину следующим образом:

```
folium_map = folium.Map(location=[lat, lon],
                    zoom_start=7,
                    tiles='https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=<идентификатор языка>&<дополнительные параметры>',
                    attr='Yandex')
```

Однако этот вариант не верен, так ка при создании карта становится полностью белой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[API Тайлов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/tiles) у Яндекса - чисто коммерческий продукт. Формат URL для загрузки тайлов [описан в документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/tiles/doc/dg/concepts/request-params.html). Тайлы же JS API Яндекса использовать без этого API и соблюдения прочих [условий сервиса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) нельзя. Это наоборот сторонние тайлы можно подключать в JS API в [кастомный слой](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Layer.html).